# I want to bypass a JavaScript snippet

Tags: python

This is a JavaScript snippet that detects the usage of developer tools and performs specific actions when detected. It appears to be designed for preventing multiple windows or tabs from opening while using a specific website (https://tickets.interpark.com/).

---

if("" != "True"){devtoolsDetector.addListener(function(e){e&&(self.opener=self,window.close(),window.location.replace("about:blank"))}),devtoolsDetector.launch();}**
**

Programmed in Python and Selenium. One Internet window turns on, but the second window turns off.
I would like to bypass this or prevent it from working. Is there a way?

I found Selenium's button element and commented out .click(), but the problem was not solved.